# How do I save this json API output to the database?

Tags: json, ruby

How do I save this json API output to the database?

The JSON output is like this:

```
[{"id"=>758426,
  "email"=>"sender@email.com",
  "created_at"=>"2014-09-23T16:23:56Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2014-09-23T16:23:58Z",
  "status"=>"Customer",
  "custom_status"=>nil,
  "first_name"=>"Name",
  "last_name"=>"Name",
  "latest_visitor"=>
   {"id"=>13940436, "tracking_code"=>"f29a780c-615a-41df-a2b1-72e5af2c466b"},
  "url"=>{"id"=>2452457, "url"=>"http://www.website.com/#_l_1a"},
  "referrer"=>nil,
  "affiliate"=>{"id"=>35521, "email"=>"sender@email.com"},
  "campaign"=>nil,
  "search_term"=>nil,
  "tracking_code"=>"f29a780c-615a-41df-a2b1-72e5af2c466b"},
 {"id"=>758845,
  "email"=>"sender@email.com",
  "created_at"=>"2014-09-23T19:27:53Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2016-03-31T19:42:17Z",
  "status"=>"Cancelled",
  "custom_status"=>"",
  "first_name"=>"Name",
  "last_name"=>"Name",
  "latest_visitor"=>
   {"id"=>14302036, "tracking_code"=>"d61e4f25-59ac-4e9a-b818-d5bc4ad73d62"},
  "url"=>nil,
  "referrer"=>nil,
  "affiliate"=>{"id"=>35579, "email"=>"sender@email.com"},
  "campaign"=>nil,
  "search_term"=>nil,
  "tracking_code"=>"d61e4f25-59ac-4e9a-b818-d5bc4ad73d62"}]
```

My problem is that there is no name for the returned array to reference the contained objects by, so I don't know what to use to grab the fields and save them.

My attempt to save the data is as follows:

```
  endpoint = 'https://api.leaddyno.com/v1/leads'
  ## API key
  request = {:params => {:key => Rails.application.secrets.LEADDYNO_PRIVATE, page: 1}}
  ## Parse JSON
  response = JSON.parse(RestClient.get endpoint, request)

  response.each do |item|
    LeaddynoLead.create(
      leaddyno_lead_id: item['id'],
      email: item['email'],
      first_name: item['first_name'],
      last_name: item['last_name'],
      latest_visitor_id: item['latest_visitor']['id'],
      latest_visitor_code: item['latest_visitor']['tracking_code'],
      url: item['url']['url'],
      referrer_id: item['referrer']['id'],
      referrer_url: item['referrer']['url'],
      leaddyno_affiliate_id: item['affiliate']['id'],
      leaddyno_affiliate_email: item['affiliate']['email'],
      search_term: item['search_term']['term'],
      search_engine: item['search_term']['search_engine'],
      leaddyno_tracking_code: item['tracking_code'],
      created_at: item['created_at'],
      updated_at: item['updated_at']
      )
      sleep 0.5
  end
```

This is the error:

```
lib/dyno.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from lib/dyno.rb:21:in `each'
    from lib/dyno.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
```

Which is this line: `referrer_id: item['referrer']['id'],`

Comment: What returned hash? I see an array with two elements, each of which is a hash. You can access its elements like any other array, e.g. `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, etc., or `arr.each` et al. If the keys match your model's attribute names and you're using Rails, you can just pass it directly to `create`, e.g. `MyModel.create(arr)` and it will create two records for you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say array. Are you saying I should just assign any name to the array? I've updated my question with the code I currently have to try and save the values.

Comment: What exactly is not working with this code?

Comment: When creating records use `create!` so any failures will be spectacular and obvious.

Comment: @infused i have edited the question to include the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your example hash, `search_term` is `nil`, so this line will fail:

```
search_term: item['search_term']['term']
```

You can guard against `item['search_term']` being nil with:

```
search_term: item.fetch('search_term', {}).fetch('term', nil)
```

You may have similar problems with other values in the hash.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly, In the case that term is a value, the value will be fetched, but if nil then it won't be fetched. Correct?

Comment: I changed the problematic values and now I get `undefined method 'fetch' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`